# How to increase memory for quarkus application?

Tags: quarkus

when quarkus application starts it logs:
QUARKUS_OPTS environment variable was not set, using default values of -Xmx24M -Xms16M -Xmn24M

How I can increase those values?
I tried set it via application.properties file:
quarkus.openshift.env.vars.QUARKUS_OPTS=-Xmx120M -Xms8M -Xmn12M

but it doesn't works.
It works if I set them via openshift but I need it in git.
Thank you.

Comment: Can you try `quarkus.kubernetes.env.vars.quarkus-opts=-Xmx120M -Xms8M -Xmn12M` please?

Do you see `QUARKUS_OPTS` being added to `target/kubernetes/openshift.yml`?

Comment: `quarkus.kubernetes.env.vars.quarkus-opts=-Xmx120M -Xms8M -Xmn12M` didn't work but `quarkus.openshift.env.vars.quarkus-opts=-Xmx124M -Xms8M -Xmn12M` added it to `target/kubernetes/openshift.yml`. Then it was build with gitlab (native profile) and deployed to ok 3.11 and I still get: QUARKUS_OPTS environment variable was not set. Could it be problem that we have old version of OKD? Thank you very much.

Comment: It likely depends on whether or not the container-image you are using supports the `QUARKUS_OPTS` environment variable.

Comment: we use these properties:
quarkus.container-image.tag=latest |
quarkus.kubernetes.deployment-target=openshift |

gitlab command:
mvn clean package -Dquarkus.profile=dev -Pnative -U -Dquarkus.container-image.build=true
|
okd/openshift: 3.11

Thank you